# iPhone simulator path not found

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

Currently I am working on video uploading app..my problem is that ,when I try to search simulator path in spotlight(I've also try this manually),I've got only **iPhoneSimulator.platform** file but in this file there are no any folders or path like **5.0/Media/DCIM** etc.

If I **Reset Contents and Settings** from iOS Simulator menu. I found above path in my **trash** folder. I think it should not be hidden at all.

Any idea..?

**XCODE 4.2**

**THANKS.**

Comment: can you tell me what code you have tried.

Comment: It's on about iPhone simulator path located on HardDisk. I posted this que. when I was working on video photo uploading proj. For testing purpose I tried to test video / photos on simulator using camera roll method. So this que. is clear as topic suggested.Thanks.

Comment: Applied for reopen. What about this que? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799405/iphone-simulator-not-found?lq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When You are working on Simulator, you Machine OS runs Behind it. :)

This is the Path where you can Find every thing Related to your Device Installation or apps Deployed by you on the Simulator :

```
/Users/"Your Home NAme "/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/Which version you use(4.3.2 "this is mine")/Applications
```

Hope you find your way now.. if any problem Reply plz..  :)

Comment: In my mac,there is only one and one iPhoneSimulator.platform

Comment: have you gone the url i told you.??

Comment: unable to access directory..thanks for taking time.

Comment: :) NO... But y u r not able to access the directory, don't u have the admin rights of that machine..?

Answer (score 0):

you want to look in "/Users/yourusername/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/". in there you'll find one or more directories corresponding to the version of iOS used. in your case you should have a "5.0" directory. in there you'll find a bunch of dirs. if you're storing data in your application's Documents directory, go to "Applications/your app's ID/Documents".