# Save image captured by Camera into Documents Directory in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios6

Hi I am new to iPhone Environment. I am using the Xcode 4.5. I am developing the Camera Application now. I want to save the image is taking from the Camera to a Separate folder in Documents Directory and also in a Custom album in Photo Library .. I am saving the images to Custom album in Photo Library but I don't know how to save it to Documents Directory... Can anyone tell me how to do this..?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.jpg"];
NSString *stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"New Folder"];
// New Folder is your folder name
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:stringPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:stringPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

NSString *fileName = [stringPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/image.jpg"];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
[data writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response..I tried this code its working but Where Do I have to seen that image to check the image size..?

Comment: Try following path : Finder -> Go -> Go to Folder -> /Users/GirishS/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator. Replace GirishS with your system name.

Comment: In Application Support it is not showing the iPhone Simulator..!

Comment: - Execute the following command on terminal to unhide the hidden folders. chflags nohidden ~/library/

Comment: iPhone Simulator is not showing after executing the above command..

Comment: Still iPhone simulator is showing or not....

Comment: It works for me, don't know why not worked for you? try following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738019/iphone-simulator-path-not-found